# How to add multiple images to a model?

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

Wagtail

My model code:

```
class HomePage(Page):

    images = models.ImagesField(max_count = 20)  // How to do it right?
   
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ImagesChooserPanel('images'),
    ]
```

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak3UH.png)

Please help!

Comment: This is covered in the tutorial: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by streamfield

```
images =  StreamField([
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

(sadly)You can't such thing as

```
images = models.ImagesField(max_count = 20)
```

but there are multiple ways you can associate multiple images to the same model as

1. using `image1 = models.ImagesField(upload_tp='somewhere') image2 = models.ImagesField(upload_tp='somewhere')`
2. second associate model to a different model using a foreign key and use the first way